# Redirect after get_delete_post_link

Tags: redirect

I've created a custom post type with front-end submission.  I added a delete link using `get_delete_post_link` ... which works great, except it brings me to a "Page not found" after the post is deleted.

I'd like to be able to redirect to another page after the post is deleted.   I know I can use the `add_filter( 'get_delete_post_link', 'some_function' )` ... but I wouldn't want that to fire every time that function is run in case I create other custom post types with front end submisison.

I know about `wp_delete_post`... but I can't call that from a link.

What would be the best way to do this?  Can't find any real solutions after some reading.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an AJAX Call from the delete post Link.

First, register the AJAX function:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpse_delete_post', 'wpse_delete_post' );
```

I would not add the AJAX function to the nopriv Users, but if you want every visitor of the site (ignoring capabilities) to be able to delete a post, you would have to add this as well:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wpse_delete_post', 'wpse_delete_post' );
```

The next thing to do is define the callback-function:

```
function wpse_delete_post() {

    // be sure to add all the security you need, so that no post gets deleted by accident or malicious intent
    $postid = intval( $_POST['post_id'] );
    // also define what you want your AJAX message to return
    if ( wp_delete_post( $postid ) === false ) {
        echo "fail";
    } else {
        echo "success";
    }

    die(); // needed to function properly

}
```

The final step would be the the AJAX call from your Link. Lets assume you have the ID available on your Link, just to make things easier:

```
<a href="#" id="POSTID" class="ajax_delete_post">delete post</a>
```

You add the following Javascript to your functions:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $(".ajax_delete_post").click( function(){
        var data =  {
            action: 'wpse_delete_post',
            post_id: $(this).val("id")
        };
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });

    });

});
```

Be sure to have `ajaxurl` defined as well, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm not super experienced with jQuery just yet.  Looking over [.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)... I'm a little confused as to what it does and how I use it here.  Also, I'm assuming I redirect in `wpse_delete_post()` if `wp_delete_post` is successful right?

Comment: Nono, the wpse_delete_post() is in the AJAX call - so it does not happen on the website. in the jQueryfunction you tell the server to call this function, and the part with `console.log` outputs the return value of the function in your console.

Comment: So, I got this to work after doing some more reading on it.  I decided to remove the post div instead of redirect.  Had to use the `$(this).attr("id")` instead of `.val()` ... I used the response to make sure the response matched the post-id of the div I wanted to remove... and then I removed it!  Thanks for pointing the direction!